# placing legend outside a dynamically changing plot R

Tags: r, plot

In my **R code below**, I have **two situations** **each resulting in a different plot** depending on `S` being **larger OR smaller** than `1`. I was wondering how I can **take out (move up) the current legend and put it above the plot at the same place for either of the resulting plots?**

***Note:*** Due to **Y axis** being on **log-scale**, I have used `10^par('usr')[4]` but I need to add **a number** to `10^par('usr')[4]` (**i.e.,** `(10^par('usr'))[4] + a number`) **such that "this number"** puts the legend in the exact same place **above** either of the resulting plots?

Here is **the R code:**

```
 S <- 0.25    ### !!!  Change this to "24" and see how another plot will appear !!! ###
Ur <- c(0.25, 24, 16)

if(S>=1){

plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(1/3, 100), log="y", bty="n", ann=F, axes=F, xaxs="i")

axis(side=1, at = seq(0,1.5,.25),labels = c("0",".25",".5",".75","1","1.25","1.5"))
axis(side=2, at = c(1/3, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100),labels = c("1/3", "1", "3", "10", "30", "100"),las=1)

}else{

plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(.01, 3), log="y", bty="n", ann=F ,axes=F, xaxs="i")

axis(side=1, at = seq(0,1.5,.25),labels = c("0",".25",".5",".75","1","1.25","1.5"))
axis(side=2, at = c(.01, 1/30, 1/10, 1/3, 1, 3),labels = c("1/100", "1/30", "1/10", "1/3", "1", "3"),las=1)
}


legend(0, (10^par("usr"))[4], bquote(paste("Selected Prior:              ",bold('PN'[10])," = ", .(round(S,3)))), ## Legend
   pch = 21,cex=2,pt.bg="green", col="red", pt.cex=2.8, bty="n")
```

Comment: I couldn't find G?

Comment: You can find the coordinates of the current plot with `par()$fig` (the x,y coordinates of the 'box'), and use this to calculate coordinates for your legend

Comment: @aelwan, I edited the code, runs well

Comment: @Remko, `par('fig')[4]` doesn't put the legend above the plotting region. So, I guess, `10^par('usr')[4]` is much better. But I need to add a number to it such that this number puts the legend in the exact same place above either of the two plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `inset` argument in `legend`.To do so, you need to use legend location as a word. In your case, `"topleft"`. This way, you do not need to provide specific location based on your "y".

The inset argument allows you to offset the legend. In the present case, the y is offset by -0.03.

I also use `par(xpd=TRUE)`to expand the allowed plotting space. Finally, I also changed the font size to produce the following charts.

```
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend("topleft", legend=bquote(paste("Selected Prior:              ",bold('PN'[10])," = ", .(round(S,3)))), ## Legend
   pch = 21,cex=1,pt.bg="green", col="red", pt.cex=2, bty="n", inset=c(0,-0.03))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Just a simple follow-up, is there any argument within the `legend()` that can control the distance between the symbol and the text that appears after the symbol? (in my case, the **distance between then the Green point and the word "Selected prior"**?)

Comment: @parvinkarimi Yes. it's `x.intersp` try `x.intersp=0.5` to get a short distance or `x.intersp=2` to increase the distance